# Yii Framework - Two instances of the same relation

Tags: php, yii, relation

I have a model `Animal` in Yii which has two relations, `mainRace` and `secondaryRace`, both of them being an instance of the `Race` model.

How can this be translated into the relations array of `Animal` model aswell as in the `Race` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'd need a many to many relationship, so you'll need one more table (animal_race).

See the [Yii Relational page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship) for more info on how to setup a MANY_MANY

Edit: if you're wanting to limit the animal to only two races, then you'd probably want to have a main_race_id / secondary_race_id in the Animal model (assuming an animal can only ever be in two races, what if the animal is entered in multiple events?).

And then you'd use a BELONGS_TO setup.  That way you can easily find all the animals for a given race using a HAS_MANY relationship.

Comment: Yes, I know about many to many relationships, but this would allow to an `Animal` model to have more than two instances of `Race`, which is not the desired behavior. Also, they are semantically different as one is main race and the other secondary. I think that I did not express the goal of the question very well.